# Loop a HTTP Post

Tags: java, http, post, get

I have a Http post in java which I need to run on loop, but on execution only my POST part is on loop, and not the GET part. I have added them together in the run();

Please help.

Comment: Maybe try printing out the exceptions, and you'll get a clue. Use e.printStackTrace() in catch statements.

Comment: Where are those from `HttpClass_get.insert` `HttpClass.insert` ? But since you have burried the exception, I would point that as a HUGE problem ;) You should read how and when to manage exception.

Comment: `HttpClass` and `HttpClass_get` are two classes where the Post and Get code is in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't instantiated the array v. You need to instantiate it like `v = new int[21]`

Comment: That is a declaration. You also have to instantiate it like v= new int[20]

Comment: Where exactly you mean?

Comment: Before you can use an array in java, you need to allocate memory by instantiating it by its size. Since the largest index you are referencing is 20, its size should be 21(including 0 too).

Comment: Currently only my `POST` part is on loop, and `GET` parts executes just once..what changes I do make to make the GET execute after each POST.. like `while (true){ post; get; }`

Comment: What are you doing with the data in the v array? It looks like it's unused.

Comment: Just for the sake of making it work, you can comment all of that out and you'll get the desired output.

Comment: Ya, it stays in my server until the client does a socket read and extract it. from me.

Comment: what do I comment?

Comment: v[0] = ... till the end of for loop.

Comment: Sure let me try running it in server..I'll get back

Comment: Thanks a lot @bilalba, it worked.. Now both are on loop ie post, get, post, get... Thanks so much.